# How do I use Node.js Crypto to create a HMAC-SHA1 hash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, hash, node-crypto

I want to create a hash of `I love cupcakes` (signed with the key `abcdeg`)

How can I create that hash, using Node.js Crypto?

Answer (score 423, accepted):

Documentation for crypto: http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

```js
const crypto = require('crypto')

const text = 'I love cupcakes'
const key = 'abcdeg'

crypto.createHmac('sha1', key)
  .update(text)
  .digest('hex')
```

Comment: 'hex' is not always needed, for example for doing the hmac digest equivalent of ruby.

Comment: And to verify a hash, you should use `crypto.timingSafeEqual(Buffer.from(a), Buffer.from(b))`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095905/whats-the-difference-between-a-secure-compare-and-a-simple/31096242#comment97670146_31096242

Comment: The circle is complete: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto

Comment: How do i set the key type to hex as well?

Answer (score 104):

A few years ago it was said that `update()` and `digest()` were legacy methods and the new streaming API approach was introduced. Now the docs say that either method can be used. For example:

```
var crypto    = require('crypto');
var text      = 'I love cupcakes';
var secret    = 'abcdeg'; //make this your secret!!
var algorithm = 'sha1';   //consider using sha256
var hash, hmac;

// Method 1 - Writing to a stream
hmac = crypto.createHmac(algorithm, secret);    
hmac.write(text); // write in to the stream
hmac.end();       // can't read from the stream until you call end()
hash = hmac.read().toString('hex');    // read out hmac digest
console.log("Method 1: ", hash);

// Method 2 - Using update and digest:
hmac = crypto.createHmac(algorithm, secret);
hmac.update(text);
hash = hmac.digest('hex');
console.log("Method 2: ", hash);
```

Tested on node v6.2.2 and v7.7.2

See https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hmac. Gives more examples for using the streaming approach.

Comment: Not a one-liner, and calls can't be daisy-chained... but I'll use this approach.

Comment: I can't, for the life of me, make this work. hmac.read() returns a " [object SlowBuffer]" and if I try to read the contents using hmac.read().toString('hex'); I do not get the expected value. If I use the update/digest deprecated approach, it returns the expected string. I'm using this to validate a signature from a third party POST to my servers. Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Perhaps the hmac.read is happening before the data has been flushed to the stream? Maybe hmac.read should be driven by the stream's finish event?

Comment: Actually the link that you posted explicitely mentions the use of `update` and not `write`. I am confused, which is best practice now? I cant find resources that tell that as clearly as you mention it.

Comment: As of Nov. 2016, `digest` and `update` have *not* been deprecated and are featured in the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hmac. I recommend using the stream API only if you're reading from a stream.

Comment: It's true, `update` and `digest` were not depreciated. When I originally answered this question in 2013 the docs said they were "legacy methods" but they were changed in 2015 to say using piped streams (as in my answer) or using `update` and `digest` (as in Ricardo's answer) are both valid methods. [Here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/cc82e5e3d9aefb5e31dbe688b0038327bb7d9b80?diff=unified#commitcomment-21891754) is where the docs were changed and [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/api/crypto.md#class-hash) are the current docs.

Comment: @AdamGriffiths works good both of them. What you recommend to use?

Answer (score 22):

Gwerder's solution wont work because `hash = hmac.read();` happens before the stream is done being finalized. Thus AngraX's issues. Also the `hmac.write` statement is un-necessary in this example.

Instead do this:

```
var crypto    = require('crypto');
var hmac;
var algorithm = 'sha1';
var key       = 'abcdeg';
var text      = 'I love cupcakes';
var hash;

hmac = crypto.createHmac(algorithm, key);

// readout format:
hmac.setEncoding('hex');
//or also commonly: hmac.setEncoding('base64');

// callback is attached as listener to stream's finish event:
hmac.end(text, function () {
    hash = hmac.read();
    //...do something with the hash...
});
```

More formally, if you wish, the line

```
hmac.end(text, function () {
```

could be written

```
hmac.end(text, 'utf8', function () {
```

because in this example text is a utf string

Comment: You are wrong, there is no need for adding a callback. This stream is synchronous and is readable right after end() is called. Most fascinating thing is it is written in official documentation, but everyone have to put their 5 (bent) cents in.

Comment: Are you trolling? Perhaps you should read the documentation. If you try to read the stream before the finish event, it will fail.

Comment: From [https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hmac]
`It is a stream that is both readable and writable. The written data is used to compute the hmac. Once the writable side of the stream is ended, use the read() method to get the computed digest.` You read it when **writable** side **ended**, you don't need to even wait for when _readable_ side becomes _readable_ (though it surely does). Read your documentation please.

Comment: createHmac creates a **stream**. "_ended_" in the documentation line you quote above does not mean `hmac.end(...)` has been called, "_ended_" means that the stream has _raised its finish event_,  which is why the command accepts a callback. After the end() method is called, the stream requires time to flush the data to the underlying system. If you call read() before the finish event is raised, it will fail. Go ahead and paster Gwerder's code into JSbin and see for yourself. You should be reading the _Streams_ documentation to understand how it works.

Comment: I've used it in production code for some time and it is stable as hell. I honestly don't know what JSBin is, but I've also tried the supported code in nodejs with just copy-paste and it works too. You shouldn't imagine additional meanings to documentation. "ended" always means "ended" everywhere in documentation. Yet again, you seem to misunderstand that stream have 2 sides. And in documentation it is explicitly stated that person can use `read()` when **writable** side ended, and there is nothing about finish event.

Comment: And even some abstract solution which reads hmacs from all over the world should not depend on _writable_ `finish` event, but on _readable_ `readable` and `end` events.

Comment: By your logic it is ok to read data when some system decides that it have done flushing all the data required to generate it, but before actual data producer generated anything. So how about not introducing extremely leaky abstractions and callback hell when we have a system(which is actually purely synchronous) which is guaranteed to work in a simple, effective and predictable way?

Answer (score 1):

Despite all the sample code for signing and verifying hashing algorithms, I still had experiment and tweak quite a bit to make it work. Here's my working sample which I believe has all edge cases covered.

It's URL safe (i.e. doesn't need to be encoded), it takes an expiry time, and will not unexpectedly throw an exception. There is a dependency on [Day.js](https://day.js.org/), but you can replace that with another date library or roll your own date comparison.

Written in TypeScript:

```
// signature.ts
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';

const key = 'some-random-key-1234567890';

const replaceAll = (
  str: string,
  searchValue: string,
  replaceValue: string,
) => str.split(searchValue).join(replaceValue);

const swap = (str: string, input: string, output: string) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    str = replaceAll(str, input[i], output[i]);

  return str;
};

const createBase64Hmac = (message: string, expiresAt: Date) =>
  swap(
    crypto
      .createHmac('sha1', key)
      .update(`${expiresAt.getTime()}${message}`)
      .digest('hex'),
    '+=/', // Used to avoid characters that aren't safe in URLs
    '-_,',
  );

export const sign = (message: string, expiresAt: Date) =>
  `${expiresAt.getTime()}-${createBase64Hmac(message, expiresAt)}`;

export const verify = (message: string, hash: string) => {
  const matches = hash.match(/(.+?)-(.+)/);
  if (!matches) return false;

  const expires = matches[1];
  const hmac = matches[2];

  if (!/^\d+$/.test(expires)) return false;

  const expiresAt = dayjs(parseInt(expires, 10));
  if (expiresAt.isBefore(dayjs())) return false;

  const expectedHmac = createBase64Hmac(message, expiresAt.toDate());
  // Byte lengths must equal, otherwise crypto.timingSafeEqual will throw an exception
  if (hmac.length !== expectedHmac.length) return false;

  return crypto.timingSafeEqual(
    Buffer.from(hmac),
    Buffer.from(expectedHmac),
  );
};
```

You can use it like this:

```
import { sign, verify } from './signature';

const message = 'foo-bar';
const expiresAt = dayjs().add(1, 'day').toDate();
const hash = sign(message, expiresAt);

const result = verify(message, hash);

expect(result).toBe(true);
```